# Cannot download quandl with python 3.7

Tags: quandl

Trying to install quandl to get into machine learning. I run python 3.7 and windows 10 and type in pip install quandl, pip3 install quandl, pip3.7 install quandl and it keeps giving me an error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: More specifically: What is the error message? And why are you using a beta release of python instead of a stable version?

Comment: I'm totally new to python, I was using 3.4 before but had issues even trying to get it to function correctly, so I just downloaded the most recent version.  Honestly, I'm just going to take Henry's advice and work on another project of mine until it gets updated.

Comment: Most probably, that won't help, since [the project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Quandl/3.3.0) seems to be compatible with more or less any Python version (and Python releases are backwards compatible).
Please include your installation commands and the error message. It will (most probably) contain useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Things to do if this is your first time installing libraries:
1.) make sure u have a path to python or a path set up in the environment
2. Try easy install
3.) there is a possibility that the library for python 3.7 isn’t out yet

Comment: Alright then, I guess I'll just work on a side project until a version for 3.7 is released.